# How to run Chrome/Firefox/Webkit engine on a Silverlight OOB browser control

Tags: .net, angularjs, google-chrome, silverlight, silverlight-oob

I am maintaining a Silverlight application that runs Out-of-Browser (OOB). I want to be able to display an Angular webpage inside of it using a WebBrowser control. (This is required to maintain the sidebar menu for all other application functionality)

From my research, the Silverlight WebBrowser control is an ActiveX wrapper based on IE (Internet Explorer), so it's very buggy with modern Angular pages.

Does a Silverlight control exist based on Chrome/Firefox/Webkit? I have looked at several popular solutions such as [Cef Sharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/cefsharp), [EO.WebBrowser](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/WebBrowser/Default.aspx), [Awesomium](http://awesomium.codeplex.com/), and the outdated [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/index.php). 
The problem is they are all for Desktop platforms such as WPF, so I can't even add references to them in my Silverlight VS Project.

Any ideas?